# Перенести сайт на Joomla

Tags: joomla, html, php, css

Сделал сайт на HTML (то есть со структурой `index.html`, папка `images, css, js` и, соответственно, страницы html в корне). Как перенести на joomla v1.7?

Answer (score 2):

В админке Джумлы есть меню, что-то типа "редактор шаблонов". Вот в нем можно создавать свои страницы и править в HTML редакторе уже имеющиеся.

Comment: Да это я знаю, только куда все html страницы всунуть?